# Marker custom dynamic icon text is blank

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Working on a project that will have live pricing across a map that needs to be updated dynamically.

I have created a custom icon like below and need to be able to dynamically update the text on the icon

```
var myIcon = L.divIcon({className: 'my-div-icon', html: '<div class="myIcon" id="test"></div>'}); 

L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 11;
```

The icon displays on the map but is blank, the number doesn't appear and no errors in the console

Still quite new to javascript and leaflet so would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Ive just figured out its because html element IDs have to be unique and I was reusing the same div ID within a loop for multiple markers.

Comment: Great, don't forget to mark this question as solved

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce.
https://codepen.io/SioGabx/pen/BaPjqow

```js
// Initialize the map and assign it to a variable for later use
// there's a few ways to declare a VARIABLE in javascript.
// you might also see people declaring variables using `const` and `let`
var map = L.map('map', {
    // Set latitude and longitude of the map center (required)
    center: [51.5, -0.09],
    // Set the initial zoom level, values 0-18, where 0 is most zoomed-out (required)
    zoom: 11
});
 

// Create a Tile Layer and add it to the map
var tiles = new L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  minZoom: '1'}).addTo(map);


var myIcon = L.divIcon({className: 'my-div-icon', html: '<div class="myIcon" id="test"></div>'}); 
L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 11;
```

```css
#map { 
  height: 100vh;
}

.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#test{
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  transform:scale(2)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unsure why mine won't work so, I can see the example given above works but I've made mine identical within the project and still nothing

Comment: Update: So I've narrowed it down some more, it works ok as one marker but I'm plotting multiple markers using a loop and it doesn't seem to work that way when its in the loop